# What is a "pulpy orange"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, adjectives, nouns

From Hemingway's *Farewell to Arms*

> The soldier would not take the penny I offered him and brought me a **pulpy orange**. I sucked on that and spit out the pith.

What is the difference between a pulpy and non-pulpy orange? I take pulp to be the orange vesicles that contain juice (Wikipedia).

Answer (score 2):

From the fact that pulpy seems to refer to the solid fibrous stuff mostly now found in (the more fancy types of) orange juice, I would say that a pulpy orange is the opposite of a juicy orange.

The fact that the protagonist proceeds to spit out the pith - the soft, spongy tissue - seems to fit with that idea.

So instead of a nice juicy orange that would leave you with juice dripping from your chin if you would bite in it, this orange was a dried out, probably far from fresh affair, which needed sucking to get some taste out of it and didn't inspire the eater to actually even swallow the thing.

Comment: Yes, the subject was also thirsty and wounded